# Spring Boot: @TestConfiguration Not Overriding Bean During Integration Test

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-test

I have a `Bean` defined in a class decorated with `@Configuration`:

```
@Configuration
public class MyBeanConfig {
    @Bean
    public String configPath() {
        return "../production/environment/path";
    }
}
```

I have a class decorated with `@TestConfiguration` that should override this `Bean`:

```
@TestConfiguration
public class MyTestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public String configPath() {
        return "/test/environment/path";
    }
}
```

The `configPath` bean is used to set the path to an external file containing a registration code that must be read during startup. It is used in an `@Component` class:

```
@Component
public class MyParsingComponent {
    private String CONFIG_PATH;
    
    @Autowired
    public void setCONFIG_PATH(String configPath) {
        this.CONFIG_PATH = configPath;
    }
}
```

While trying to debug this I set a breakpoint inside each method as well as the constructor of the test config class. The `@TestConfiguration`'s constructor breakpoint is hit, so i know that my test configuration class instantiates, however the `configPath` method of that class is never hit. Instead, the `configPath` method of the normal `@Configuration` class is hit and the `@Autowired` `String` in `MyParsingComponent` is always `../production/environment/path` rather than the expected `/test/environment/path`.

Not sure why this is happening. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your test class annotated with `@Import(MyTestConfiguration.class)`?

Comment: @SamBrannen It wasn't there. And adding it didn't work. But changing it to `@ContextConfiguration(MyTestConfiguration.class)` did. Still don't understand why the @Primary annotation was being ignored without the  `ContextConfiguration`, though.

Comment: As documented in the Spring Boot reference manual, any beans configured in a top-level class annotated with `@TestConfiguration` will not be picked up via component scanning. So that's why you have to explicitly declare it.

Comment: If you class annotated with `@TestConfiguration` were a static nested class within your test class, it would be used automatically.

Comment: If that answers your question(s), I can make it a formal _answer_. ;-)

Comment: @SamBrannen That would be good. Thanks much for the help and explainations.

Comment: I found that if you have some another class in `@ContextConfiguration(classes=...)` `@TestConfiguration` will not work anymore. So you have to add your class with configuration explicitly to `@ContextConfiguration(classes=...)`.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

As documented in the [Detecting Test Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config) section of the Spring Boot reference manual, any beans configured in a top-level class annotated with `@TestConfiguration` will **not** be picked up via component scanning. So you have to explicitly register your `@TestConfiguration` class.

You can do that either via `@Import(MyTestConfiguration.class)` or `@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyTestConfiguration.class)` on your test class.

On the other hand, if your class annotated with `@TestConfiguration` were a `static` nested class *within* your test class, it would be registered automatically.

Comment: I try to do a test with #TestConfiguration placed on a top-level class and with #Import(MyTestConfiguration.class) and without #TestConfiguration but with #Import(MyTestConfiguration.class). The result was equal. Does it mean that #TestConfiguration is useless?

Comment: `@TestConfiguration` is still useful. Please consult the linked documentation for details.

Comment: The URL is dead

Comment: I fixed the link due to changes in Spring Boot 2.2's documentation. Thanks

Comment: I would like to reuse `@TestConfiguration` for multiple test classes hence having an abstract test class all the others do inherit might be an option. Unfortunately, `@TestConfiguration` is not picked up if it is in the abstract class the current test inherits from. @SamBrannen is it by design? How to share `@TestConfiguration` in-between test classes?

Comment: Why I can not override a spring bean (with same name) with ```@Import```  annotation .. I can override with ```@ContextConfiguration``` and static inner class annotated as  ```@TestConfiguration```

Comment: Just a heads up, try both `@Import(Your.class)` and `@ContextConfiguration(classes = Your.class)` one after the other. Not sure why, but the former didn't work out for me. However, the latter did!

Comment: It did not work for me, in Kotlin, using @Import, but it IS working using `@ContextConfiguration(classes = [TestConfiguration::class])`.

Comment: When using `@Import`, I also needed to annotated the overriden bean with `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "beanNameToOverride")`

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Could you please take a look MRE? https://github.com/gredwhite/springboottestconfigissue_demo

Currently example is working but if you change packaga or name for MyConfiguration which resides in test - app won't start

Comment: What is wrong here in my MRE https://github.com/gredwhite/springboottestconfigissue_demo/tree/bug/config_issue ?

Comment: I tried to repeat the advise but no luck. Could you please take a look?https://github.com/gredwhite/springboottestconfigissue_demo/tree/bug/config_issue

Comment: if you do an explicit @Import, there is no need for any other annotation (@Configuration or @TestConfiguration) on the class.

Comment: if your class annotated with TestConfiguration were a static nested class within your test class, it would still not necessarily be registered automatically. For example if using SpringBootTest(classes={...}) any extra configuration must be either explicitly listed in classes, or brought in using import

Answer (score 57):

Make sure that the method name of your @Bean factory method does not match any existing bean name. I had issues with method names like *config()* or (in my case) 
 *prometheusConfig()* which collided with existing bean names. Spring skips those factory methods **silently** and simply does not call them / does not instantiate the beans.

If you want to override a bean definition in your test, use the bean name explicitly as string parameter in your @Bean("beanName") annotation.

Comment: this is the actual answer. I have a nested static class with @TestConfiguration and it wasn't working. The problem was that the factory method was named the same as the actual bean.

Comment: In my very peculiar case I had to add `@Primary` as well. Otherwise it would just throw `expected single matching bean but found 2`.

Comment: Marcel, this has been your first and only answer on SO - but it's a life saver! Thank you so much <3

Comment: What is wrong here in my MRE https://github.com/gredwhite/springboottestconfigissue_demo/tree/bug/config_issue ?

Answer (score 14):

- Test configuration has to be explicitly imported in the test via `@Import({MyTestConfiguration.class})`.
- The name of the `@Bean` methods in `@Configuration` and `@TestConfiguration` have to be different. At least it makes difference in Spring Boot v2.2.
- Also make sure `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` otherwise the bean could not be overriden.

Comment: Your 2nd and 3rd bullet statements fo conflict with each other - the bean override mechanism implies the bean names do match.

Comment: What is wrong here in my MRE https://github.com/gredwhite/springboottestconfigissue_demo/tree/bug/config_issue ?

Answer (score 14):

For me worked this code:

```
  @TestConfiguration // 1. necessary
  public class TestMessagesConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary // 2. necessary
    public MessageSource testMessageSource() { // 3. different method name than in production code e.g. add test prefix

    }
  }
```

Comment: for me too this only seems to be working. Tried the above 2 answers but none of them worked. Not sure why the Main Configuration is read by Spring even for test case when we have static nested class with @TestConfiguration annotation.

Comment: What is wrong here in my MRE https://github.com/gredwhite/springboottestconfigissue_demo/tree/bug/config_issue ?

Answer (score 6):

I struggled with a related problem, whereby even though I was using an inner static class, my test bean was not being registered.

It turns out, You still need to add your inner static class to the `@ContextConfiguration` class array, otherwise the beans inside the @TestConfiguration doesn't get picked up.

```
public interface Foo {
    String execute();
}
```

```
public class FooService {
    private final Foo foo;

    FooService(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public String execute() {
        return foo.execute();
    }
}
```

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {FooService.class, FooTest.FooTestConfig.class})
public class FooTest {
    @Autowired
    FooService fooService;

    @Test
    void test() {
        Assertions.assertEquals("MY_TEST_BEAN", fooService.execute());
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    static class FooTestConfig {
        @Bean
        public Foo getFooBean() {
            return () -> "MY_TEST_BEAN";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the only thing that helped, thank you for your answer.

Comment: In case of `@TestConfiguration` being a static inner class in your test class, no need to explicitly register the configuration class, it will be picked up automatically.

Answer (score 5):

In my case replacing @`Import(TestConfig.class)` with `@ContextConfiguration(classes=TestConfig.class)` did the trick. For some reason, some of the beans from TestConfig but 1 wasn't until I replaced `@Import` with `@ContextConfiguration`.
This was also mentioned in some comments that were hidden because they had no upvotes.

Comment: What is wrong here in my MRE https://github.com/gredwhite/springboottestconfigissue_demo/tree/bug/config_issue ?

Answer (score 2):

I came across a similar issue recently and got it sorted out by annotating my testing bean with @Primary as well as @Bean. Not sure why it's required, which seems not documented in the Spring doc. The version of my SpringBoot is 2.0.3.

Comment: I was searching for hours for this answer! Thank you, it worked

Answer (score 2):

I found it odd how several answers stated that the names of the `@Bean`s have to be different from each other. How would that make one override the other?
There wasn't one specific answer that worked for me, but I've solved the issue by combining some of their advices.

Here's what worked for me.

Main configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration {

    @Bean
    BeanInterface myBean() {
        return new BeanImplementation();
    }
    
    @Bean
    OtherClass otherBean() {
        return new OtherClass();
    }
}
```

Test configuration class:

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestSpringConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    BeanInterface myBean() {
        return new TestBeanImplementation();
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestSpringConfiguration.class, 
        properties = "spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true")
public class Tests {
    
    @Test
    public void test() {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

In this way, the "myBean" bean instance is the one defined in the `TestSpringConfiguration` class, while "otherBean" is the one defined in the `SpringConfiguration` class, since it's not overridden.
If I gave two different names to the "myBean" beans, the "real" one would still be initialized and, in my case, would give an error during tests, since it needs something that's only available at runtime in its proper environment.
Once I gave both the same name, Spring would throw an error saying that they were conflicting. Hence why I had to specify the property `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` in the `@SpringBootTest` annotation of the test class.

By the way, if you're **NOT** using Spring Boot, I guess these alternative annotations could work for you:

```
@ExtendWith(value = SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, // <- not sure about this one
        classes = { SpringConfiguration.class, TestSpringConfiguration.class })
public class Tests {
    
    @Test
    public void test() {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Then, you would still have to set the property `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` in the test `application.yml` or `application.properties` file, or in some other way via code on startup.

Note: I'm not 100% sure that you would need the `loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class` thing. Try without it, first. I needed it in a project of mine which had Spring without Boot, but I can't remember whether it's a standard thing to set or I needed it for some specific reason.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an issue with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`, I'm not exactly sure why it wasn't working, I was following this - [Testing in Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing)

But after replacing that with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` the inner static `@TestConfiguration` class created the beans as expected.

Maybe a version mismatch - I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.2.