# @primary annotation is not working for JUnit tests

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring application where I am using EasyMock for mocking in JUnit tests.

I have three classes (let's say A and B and C) defined below.

```java
@Named("A")
@Primary
public class A {
}

@Named("B")
public class B extends A {
}

public class C {
  @Inject
  private A a; // It should inject A instance here since it is marked as primary
}


public class CTest {

@Mock
private A a;// Here I'm getting exception
}
```

When I run tests in CTest class, I'm getting error
***expected single matching bean but found 2:(A and B).***

Why @primary annotation is not working here.

Comment: Usually Profile work together with Bean annotation. Can you try it instead of Name?

Comment: Very similiar to a question i asked a while back. See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607285/spring-boot-testconfiguration-not-overriding-bean-during-integration-test

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might need below config.

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

If overriding is for test only, you can try it in the test profile.

ref - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#bean-overriding