# How to use @TestConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot

How to override @Configuation which is present under src/main/java with @TestConfiguration during unit tests?

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    

    @Bean
    public EmployeeService employeeService(){
        return new EmployeeService();
    }


}


@Component
public class ServerStartSetup implements CommandLineRunner {
    

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    public void run(String... args) {
        // do something with employee service
    }

}
```

I would like to override the above bean with some below custom bean for testing purposes.

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestAppConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public EmployeeService employeeService(){
        return new FakeEmployeeService();
    }

}


@SpringBootTest
@Import(TestAppConfig.class)
public class UnitTest {
    



}
```

However AppConfig does not seem to be skipped. That is , it throws an error saying that there is a bean with same name `employeeService`. If I rename bean method name in the `TestAppConfig`, it injects the bean created via `AppConfig`.

How to fix this.?

Note: One possible solution is using `@Profile`. I am looking for anything other than using Profiles.

Comment: See [documentation of `@TestConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/TestConfiguration.html): "@Configuration that can be used to define additional beans or customizations for a test. Unlike regular `@Configuration` classes the use of `@TestConfiguration` does not prevent auto-detection of `@SpringBootConfiguration`.". Since it is meant to define additional stuff only for testing, if you want to override existing beans, you might have better luck with `@Configuration` instead.

Comment: Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54688203/365237)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot: @TestConfiguration Not Overriding Bean During Integration Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607285/spring-boot-testconfiguration-not-overriding-bean-during-integration-test)

Comment: @eis, No it does not. Note that I am already using `@Import`the answer suggested in the other question. You should remove your close vote.

Comment: you are using Import, but you are not using the suggested naming in the answer I linked from that thread. Please read the thread, not just the accepted answer. ("If you want to override a bean definition in your test, use the bean name explicitly as string parameter in your @Bean("beanName") annotation.")

Comment: I saw that too.  It would not help at all. I tried. it throws an error 2 beans found.

Comment: so it did help? along with "I had to add @Primary as well. Otherwise it would just throw expected single matching bean but found 2"-change?

Comment: Understood. Thanks.

Comment: @eis, Thanks for being patient and clarifying. I upvoted your couple of your other answers.

Answer (score 2):

I tested locally and found that changing the method name or @Bean to @Bean("fakeEmployeeService") and adding the @Primary annotation works.

```
@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;


    @TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfig {

        //@Bean("fakeEmployeeService")
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public EmployeeService employeeServiceTest() {
            return new EmployeeService() {
                @Override
                public void doSomething() {
                    System.out.println("Do something from test...");
                }
            };
        }
    }
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If we want to override a bean definition in `@TestConfiguration`, we need:

1. To use the same name as the overridden bean. (Otherwise it would be an "additional" bean and we could get conflict/'d have to qualify/primary)
2. Since spring-boot:2.1: `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` (set this in tests ONLY!plz!)

[#ref](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.core.spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding)

Then, with:

```java
@TestConfiguration
public class TestAppConfig {
    
    @Bean // when same name, no @Primary needed
    public EmployeeService employeeService(){ // same name as main bean!
        return new FakeEmployeeService();
    }

}
```

We can do that:

```java
@Import(TestAppConfig.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = "spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true")
public class UnitTest {
  ... // EmployeeService will be "fake", the rest is from "main config"
```

Answer (score -2):

You can mock the AppConfig bean in your test like this:

```
 @MockBean
 private AppConfig config;
```

Or, like you said, just use profiles.

Comment: @MockBean does not replace bean. As I said, I am looking for other options other than profiles.