# How to put H2 test dependency in "test" scope without duplicating JPA config class?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, h2

I have this JPA configuration class which is in the regular classpath (not in test classpath) and I don't want to duplicate it (I don't want one copy for runtime, and one copy for test) :

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:persistence-${env:int}.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "fr.tristan.demoassurance.infrastructure.repository.mysql")
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class PersistenceJpaConfig {

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(Environment env) {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource(env));
        em.setPackagesToScan("fr.tristan.demoassurance.infrastructure.repository.mysql.entity");

        final JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties(env));

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource(Environment env) {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName")));
        dataSource.setUrl(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.url")));
        dataSource.setUsername(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.user")));
        dataSource.setPassword(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass")));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(Environment env) {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory(env).getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    final Properties additionalProperties(Environment env) {
        final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", env.getProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", env.getProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache"));
        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

It relies on 2 properties file, only one is loaded using -Denv=int or -Denv=dev (or just no param since "int" is the default env value) :

- persistence-dev.properties
- persistence-int.properties

If I put my H2 dependency in "test" scope instead of the default "compile" scope,

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

and I run my tests using `mvn clean verify -Denv=dev`, I get this error :

```
2023-05-31T13:04:27.200+02:00 ERROR 17240 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener] to prepare test instance [fr.tristan.demoassurance.DemoAssuranceServiceIntegrationTest@578483bd]
(...)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [org.h2.Driver]
```

Comment: oh is it ? I think the test scope is about the test being test classes or not being in test classes, not related to integration or unit test. Do u have a source for that ?

Comment: I was not precise in my comment. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I've found fulfilling all my requirements :

create a PersistenceJpaTestConfig in a package of "src/test/java" and make it extend the conf you don't want to duplicate :

```java
@Configuration
public class PersistenceJpaTestConfig extends PersistenceJpaConfig {
}
```

Now you can put the h2 dependency in "test" scope because the config class using the H2 dependency is in target/test-classes :

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: if you would like to favour composition over inheritance, you may use  `@Import(PersistenceJpaConfig.class)` instead of `extends PersistenceJpaConfig`.

Comment: is using `@Import` a "composition" though ? How would I override one of the bean method after using `@Import` ?

Comment: [Enabling bean overriding feature and using `@TestConfiguration` instead of `@Configuration`](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-testconfiguration/) in your test configuration classes.

Answer (score 0):

You may use component based "composition".

Spring Testing Swiss knife packs `@TestConfiguration` to modify Spring’s application context during test runtime. You can use it to override certain bean definition within your tests.

In addition, you must enable bean overriding behavior:

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

> The bean overriding feature is disabled by default from [Spring Boot 2.1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#bean-overriding). A [BeanDefinitionOverrideException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionOverrideException.html) is thrown if we attempt to override one or more beans.

Note that, There is no need to explicitly register `PersistenceJpaConfig`. However, If it isn't chosen by component scanning when the application context is built during your tests execution, You may add `@Import(PersistenceJpaConfig.class)` above your test configuration class name.

Furthermore, You have to explicitly register your `@TestConfiguration` class, using `@ContextConfiguration` on your test class or `@SpringBootTest(classes = PersistenceJpaTestConfig.class)`.

For instance:

```java
@TestConfiguration
// @Import(PersistenceJpaConfig.class) uncomment if, 
//it isn't chosen by component scanning when the application context is built.
public class PersistenceJpaTestConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return mock(DataSource.class);
    }   
}

@SpringBootTest(
        classes = PersistenceJpaTestConfig.class,
        properties = "spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true")
class ApplicationTests {
   ....
}
```

All beans registered within `PersistenceJpaConfig.class` should be loaded, but `dataSource` bean should be overridden by `PersistenceJpaTestConfig.dataSource()`.

You may find an example [here](https://github.com/ehayik/bootiful-beans-overriding).

sources:

- [Testing with Spring Boot’s @TestConfiguration Annotation](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-testconfiguration/)
- [Spring Boot: @TestConfiguration Not Overriding Bean During Integration Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607285/spring-boot-testconfiguration-not-overriding-bean-during-integration-test)

Comment: "There is no need to explicitly register PersistenceJpaConfig" : I extend it from a class in src/test/java so that "test" scope is enough for H2 dependency.