# @TestConfiguration annotation doesn't override bean from production configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-boot-test, spring-context

Based on

- https://sylhare.github.io/2020/07/17/Testing-with-spring-boot.html
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing#unit-testing-with-webmvctest
- [Spring Boot: @TestConfiguration Not Overriding Bean During Integration Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607285/spring-boot-testconfiguration-not-overriding-bean-during-integration-test?rq=2)

I've created test example where I want to replace production bean in tests.

Production configuration requires special properties in `application.yaml`(for demo purpose)

```
package com.example.demo.app
...

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyProperties::class)
open class MyConfiguration(
    private val myProperties: MyProperties
) {
    @Bean
    open fun propertiesHolder(): PropertiesHolder {
        return PropertiesHolder(arrayOf(myProperties.prop1, myProperties.prop2, myProperties.prop3))
    }
}
```

In tests

```
package com.example.demo.app
...

@TestConfiguration
open class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    open fun propertiesHolder(): PropertiesHolder = mockk()
}
```

And test looks like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    classes = [MyConfiguration::class]
)
class DemoControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var testRestTemplate: TestRestTemplate

    @Test
    fun getItems_success() {

    }
}
```

This works. But if I change name of package or name of class

```
@TestConfiguration
    open class MyConfigurationNewName {
```

In both cases I see the error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'propertiesHolder', defined in com.example.demo.app.MyConfigurationNewName, could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [com/example/demo/app/MyConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

I also tried to use `@Import` annotation but result is the same:

```
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
)
@Import(MyConfigurationNewName::class)
```

I tried to follow the error message

```
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
```

But another error arised after that:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'my.props' to com.example.demo.app.MyProperties:

    Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.example.demo.app.MyProperties.<init>, parameter prop1

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

I am out of ideas. Could you please help ?

The whole codebase could be found here:

https://github.com/gredwhite/springboottestconfigissue_demo

Branch with issue is: https://github.com/gredwhite/springboottestconfigissue_demo/tree/bug/config_issue

**P.S.**

I tried spring boot versions

- 3.0.1
- 3.1.0
- 3.1.4

Comment: I suspect the issue is that `@SpringBootTest` tries to load the configuration from the `@SpringBootApplication` by default, which in turn tries to load that configuration class. If both the `@Configuration` and the `@TestConfiguration` define the same fully-qualified class, the latter "wins" over the regular one. 
If you add the `classes` parameter to your `@SpringBootTest`, the main application config shouldn't be loaded and I believe everything should work even if you move the class to another package – haven't tried it though

Comment: however, I don't think you can rename the config class because by default autowiring is by type. If you want it to be by name instead, you should use `@Qualifier`

Comment: @user2340612 this action is described in the topic but no luck.  The branch with that change is here: https://github.com/gredwhite/springboottestconfigissue_demo/tree/bug/BlakeSolution

Comment: @user2340612 I would appreciate if you clone that simple example and make it working

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is essentially a duplicate of [Override default Spring-Boot application.properties settings in Junit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669393/override-default-spring-boot-application-properties-settings-in-junit-test).

You have defined an `application.yml` file at `src/main/resources` and also at `src/test/resources`. This means when your tests run there is only a single file available on the classpath (the one in `src/test/resources`).

When `MyConfiguration` is processed the `@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyProperties::class)` annotation is respected and the `MyProperties` data class is bound. This class requires non-null values but since your test `application.yml` file does not define `my.property` values you get the following exception:

```
Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.example.demo.app.MyProperties.<init>, parameter prop1
```

The test passes if I update your code by renaming `src/test/resources/application.yml` to `src/test/resources/application-test.yml` and adding `properties = ["spring.config.additional-location=classpath:application-test.yml"]` to `@SpringBootTest` annotation.

Comment: Hello Phil. Did you get that my aim is avoid loading 'MyConfiguration' so I've created 'MyConfigurationTest'. Thus I expect that property file won't be loaded at all

Comment: No, it wasn't clear to me that you wanted to avoid loading `MyConfiguration` as well as replacing the `PropertiesHolder`. If you want to do that, I would recommend looking at the `@Profile` annotation. You can annotate your `MyConfiguration` with `@Profile("!test")` then enable a test profile using `@ActiveProfiles`.

Comment: but it is mentioned in the very first phrase of the topic! And 'PropertiesHolder' won't be loaded if 'MyConfiguration' is not loaded

Comment: yes, it will work but I expected that TesConfiguration annotation is invented specifically for that purpose without using profile. Isn't it ? Also I don't want production beans know about my test profile

Comment: As described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607285/spring-boot-testconfiguration-not-overriding-bean-during-integration-test?rq=2

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the purpose of `@TestConfiguration` as it is not designed replace other `@Configuration` classes. As the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/TestConfiguration.html) explains that it "can be used to define additional beans or customizations for a test". When the test in your sample runs it find `MyConfiguration` and `MyConfigurationTest`, it will create two `PropertiesHolder` beans, one of which is primary. If a bean is `@Primary` it means it will be injected if there are multiple candidates.

Comment: Well. Is it also incorrect ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50643036/2674303

Comment: Please read question also

Comment: I don't see how that link contradicts my comments. They are not replacing the `configPath` bean, they are declaring a `@Primary` alternative that should be injected when the test is running.

Comment: Well, it makes sense for me now. So topic title is confusing. Isn't it?